# Restful API works locally but angular frontend won't work when deployed to heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

So as mentioned in the title, I had this project working on my localhost but since I've deployed to heroku it doesnt. I can still access the DB via the api and display the json but the front end file doesn't work.

At the homepage I just get cannot GET /

Server.js

```js
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // req.body
const cors = require('cors'); // 8080
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uriUtil= require('mongodb-uri');
let patients = require('./data');

const mongodbUri = 'mongodb://*********:***********@ds056009.mlab.com:56009/pt-db';
const mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
const dbOptions = {};

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(cors());



//app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //res.sendFile(__direname + '/index.html')
//});

app.use('/api/patients', require('./api/patients/routes/post_patient'));
app.use('/api/patients', require('./api/patients/routes/get_patients'));
app.use('/api/patients', require('./api/patients/routes/get_patient'));
app.use('/api/patients', require('./api/patients/routes/put_patient'));
app.use('/api/patients', require('./api/patients/routes/delete_patient'));


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  mongoose.connect(mongooseUri, dbOptions, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
  });
});
```

public/js/app.js

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('patientsApp', []);

    app.controller('patientsController', function($scope, $http) {

      $http.get('api/patients')
        .then(function(response) {
          $scope.patients = response.data;
        });
    
      $scope.savePatient = function(patient) {
        $http.post('api/patients', patient)
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.patients.push(response.data);
        });
      }
      
    });
})();
```

public/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="patientsApp">
<head>
  <title>Patient DB</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
  <body ng-controller="patientsController">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form ng-submit="savePatient(patient)">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="patient.first_name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="patient.last_name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Hospital Number" ng-model="patient.hosp_num" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Consultant" ng-model="patient.consultant" class="form-control"> 
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Treatment Site" ng-model="patient.treat_site" class="form-control"> 
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Treatment Group" ng-model="patient.treat_group" class="form-control"> 
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="patient in patients">
            <h4>Patient Name: {{patient.first_name + ' ' + patient.last_name}}</h4>
            <p>Hospital Number: {{patient.hosp_num}}</p>
            <p>Consultant: {{patient.consultant}}</p>
            <p>Treatment Site: {{patient.treat_site}}</p>
            <p>Treatment Group: {{patient.treat_group}}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

api/patients/gets_patients.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Patient = require('../model/Patient');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
  .get((req, res) => {

    Patient.find({}, (err, patients) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err);
      }
      res.json(patients);
    });
    
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Hope this makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change your url from 'api/' to '/api/' in angular

Comment: Are you serving the anguar files through your nodeJs server?

Comment: Hmm I think so yeah.

Comment: If you're not sure, then in the url put the full path like "http://yourdomainname.com/api/"

Comment: In which file am I editing this? the server.js?

Comment: Hmm thats not worked. Do i need to do something like //app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //res.sendFile(__direname + '/index.html')
//});

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Is the error that, you are not able to even get your index.html??

Comment: Yeah the index.html page doesn't show at all.

Comment: In that case you have to //app.get('/', function(req, res) { //res.sendFile(__direname + '/index.html') //}); This is the piece of code that actually serves your index.html  !! Without it your front end wont load!

Comment: app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html')
}); is what I'm using but it says internal server error and 2017-01-19T12:36:56.608615+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
2017-01-19T12:36:56.608648+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.sendFile (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:404:11)
2017-01-19T12:36:56.608650+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/server.js:22:7

Comment: Actually got the index.html showing now but its not working with the API so bleh

Comment: what error are you  getting in the API

Comment: https://murmuring-ocean-78954.herokuapp.com/ basically the form and display now doesn't work

Comment: That's because it is not able to load the angular.js library.

Comment: Any ideas why? As far as i can see the lib reference is there. I've tried it both ways CDN and installed it via npm.

Answer (score 1):

1. The main issue why you index.html was not loading was because you had commented out your middleware which serves your index.html.
2. Now that your index.html is served, It is not able to get the angular.js file which is because, the node_modules folder needs to be set to static for the node backend to serve the files.

You can do it like this :

```
var path = require('path');//Require the nodeJs's path module.
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/node_modules')));//declare as static the node_modules folder so that node can serve the angular.js file inside it
```

EDIT :

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/public")));
```

Also serve the /public folder which has the rest of your files the same way as above.

serve the angular.js file through cdn or create a bundle.js using webpack or gulp..serving node_modules will be a pain..

Comment: and that's in the server.js yes?

Comment: yes. In the server.js just before the //app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //res.sendFile(__direname + '/index.html')
//});

Comment: Hmm still not working although i'm grateful for your help. Could you contribute the code in the git repo? https://github.com/MojoJojo86/ptdb

Comment: Check the edit.. I will try to contribute to the repo when i find time.. in the meanwhile you can explore the options i have given in the Edit. Also upvote if you found my answer useful..

Comment: I've done everything you suggested and its still not working. Sorry.

Comment: The answer that i have given is correct. Would appreciate it if you could put in some effort to understand what's happening here and modify it to your code.. Go through this docs : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html